# AWS EC2 Instance (amazon Linux) refused connecting Custom TCP ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, port, amazon-linux-2

I have created an EC2 (Amazon Linux) on Aws. I have a flask server which is running on port 8080. And have opened the same port in security group.

But the EC2 refused to connect on the 8080 port (xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8080), while the port 80 is accessible, I have Nginx running on port 80.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the setup using the flask example and works for me : https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/flask-hello-world/

Steps:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxKzp.png) Launch a new Amazon EC-2 Instance (used Amazon Linux AMI)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKhCU.png) Installed Python and pip.

[3] Created a new web.py file, (modified the port from 5000 to 8080 and added rule in the security group for EC2)

[4] Ran, python3 web.py

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you done anything else other then adding the port in security group? and thank you for doing all this.

Comment: No nothing, but this is just my test Environment. If you are running something in a production Environment or in a network inside your company it is possible that you may need to whitelist the port if there is any firewall. To test this you can do a curl to localhost at port 8080 to see if the application is working.